# Write and Read binary file

Tags: java, file, binaryfiles

I have a test: Write number from 50000 to 60000 to file with any format, then read this data to original number (**file size limit 20kb**) and **cannot use writeShort() method to write or read**. But i cannot read file to original number, my code below:

This is write

```
 DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\mydata2.txt"));
            for (int i = 50000; i <= 60000; i++) {
                out.write(i);//write() just write 8-bit
            }
            out.close();
```

This is read

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\mydata2.txt"));
    int i=0;
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        System.out.print(in.readUnsignedByte()+" ");
    }
    in.close();
```

Output like this:

> 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101
> 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118
> 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135
> 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152
> 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169
> 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186
> 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203
> 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220
> 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237
> 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254
> 255 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
> 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
> 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
> 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93
> 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112
> 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129
> 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146
> 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163
> 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180
> 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189

Comment: What output are you seeing? Is there an error or just nothing at all? And, have you eyeballed the file to check if there's anything in it?

Comment: Yeah, i added ouput. And file i wrote have data, i guess it is number from 50000 to 60000 was written as byte

Comment: [Yes `DataOutputStream.write(int)` only writes the low byte as stated in the documentation that programmers should read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(int)). To write a number that needs two bytes in a two-byte space without `writeShort`, try thinking about ways you could get different bits out of an `int` (and put them back together if you also can't use `readShort`) [using expressions in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html)

Comment: 1. You can't fit values between 50,000 and 60,000 into an unsigned byte, so your code already doesn't make sense. 2. `available() > 0` is not a valid test for end of stream: remove it.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks, i'll note this. But my code worked in this case and my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it:

You do not write short, but you write the bytes of it. And the same logic for read too.

```java
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\New\\mydata2.txt"));

for (int i = 50000; i <= 60000; i++)
{
    ByteBuffer dbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    dbuf.putShort((short) i);
    byte[] bytes = dbuf.array();
    out.writeByte(bytes[0]);
    out.writeByte(bytes[1]);
}
out.flush();
out.close();

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\New\\mydata2.txt"));
byte[] buf = new byte[2];

while (in.available() > 0)
{
    buf[0] = in.readByte();
    buf[1] = in.readByte();

    // Since Short keyword cannot be used, we could use the following way to get the numbers:
    int num = (0xff & buf[0]) << 8  |
                    (0xff & buf[1]);

     System.out.print(num +" ");
}
in.close();
```

Check [this](https://javadeveloperzone.com/java-basic/java-convert-int-to-byte-array/) to understand the last conversion with `shift` operators.

Comment: But file size not correct. File size limit is 20kb

Comment: Wrong approach I think. Your task says you can't use `writeShort`, which is a hint which I interpret as being an instruction to implement `DataOutput` 'manually'. Have another think ;) Hint: each number will take two bytes to store

Comment: yup, cannot use **writeShort** or **readShort**

Comment: @g00se can you describe this for detail

Comment: Hmm. This is obviously classwork. Using `ByteBuffer` makes it more or less as easy as using `DataOutput` so I'm not sure that's going to cut it with 'teacher'… If the teacher is a good one, (s)he'll say something like "That's great. Extra marks for using NIO. Since you've been so good, here's an extra exercise for you so you can demonstrate you've mastered bit arithmetic"

Comment: @Renis1235 Thank you so much for this way. It beats me two days...... Thanks for your help. By the way i'm not student anymore i'm a trainee and i haven't researched this before

Comment: Sorry one again, but my mentor didn't allow use any **Short** word, only **Read** and **Write** numbers as **2 byte**

Answer (score 2):

Here's your clue for the 'hard part'. You must do the rest:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[2];
// (In loop)
buf[0] = (byte)(n >> 8);
buf[1] = (byte)(n & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Yes, it worked for write.  Let me research for read this